# I have a broken iPad that is being replaced tomorrow, is there any chance I could still keep the broken one?

Tags: ipad

I got an iPad mini on Wednesday through the post but I opened it to find it damaged. It is only a tiny chip but I rang apple and they are sending me a new one and I am giving this one back. Does anyone think thar it might be possible for me to buy the broken iPad from apple for cheap? It's chipped in the front and engraved on the back so surely it would make more sense for me to buy it as my sister has expressed an interest in it.

Has anyone been in this kind of situation?
Thanks.

Comment: There really is no way to know. Call them and ask, they most likely won't allow that. Welcome to Ask Different, and please read the [faq] :)

Answer (score 4):

As a former Apple employee, I can tell you this is not possible. Apple will use undamaged parts from the one you return to create refurbished units that are sold online, as well as service replacements for Genius Bars. If they shipped you the replacement in advance, you could technically just not return the damaged unit, but you will be charged for it after a certain number of days (I believe 30).

If your sister wants a good deal on one I would keep an eye out on the refurbished section of the [Apple Online Store](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/ipad), or on Craigslist or eBay.

Answer (score 0):

I can't for sure say "no way" but I would be amazed if they agreed to it, if nothing else because they have such stringent and complicated internal policies.  Your best bet would be contacting AppleCare or 1-800-My-Apple and working your way up to a manager or tier 2.  You *might* find someone that can somehow sell you the damaged one with a 10-20% discount.

Again, I wouldn't bet on this by any means but stranger things have happened I suppose.

Let us know if it works out for you!